# print the probabilities in a ordered list in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, xgboost

I'm trying to use the following chunk in a shiny code to print each class predicted by an xgboost model, with its respective prediction probability.

```
output$variableValues <- renderPrint({
  pred_probabilities <- as.data.frame(predict(model, new_data, type = "prob"))
  print(pred_probabilities)
})
```

The output looks like this:

```
.pred_1 .pred_2 .pred_3 .pred_4 .pred_5
1  0.1136476 0.1755307 0.1819535 0.08851632 0.05145776
```

Is there a way to print this prediction in a ordered list?

Comment: Generally questions should include evidence of efforts. This is not a code writing service. You might improve the probability of a response if you include code that sets up a Shiny window.

Comment: I would just like to know if there is a simpler way to do it, like a function. I looked in the function documentation and couldn't find anything, so I thought maybe someone in the community knew of a more elegant solution. Anyway, I posted the solution I came up with, although it's not elegant, it works well. Thank you.

Comment: Simpler than what? There’s no Shiny code or data to run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I changed the observeEvent function to transform my dataset into a dataframe, then used the predict function with type=prob. Then I have transposed the X and Y axis, like the code below:

```
observeEvent(input$printButton, {
  new_data <- data.frame(
    age = as.numeric(input$age),
    weight = as.numeric(input$weight),
    height = as.numeric(input$height),
    Tclass = NA
  )
   pred_probabilities_transposed <- t(pred_probabilities)
   class_names_df <- data.frame(Class = rownames(pred_probabilities_transposed))
   pred_probabilities_with_names <- cbind(class_names_df, pred_probabilities_transposed)
   colnames(pred_probabilities_with_names) <- c("Class", "Probability")
   pred_probabilities_with_names <- pred_probabilities_with_names %>%
     arrange(desc(Probability)) 
 
   output$variableValues <- renderTable({
     pred_probabilities_with_names
   }, rownames = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: this is not quite 'idiomatic' for shiny... recommend you seperate out the data creation (that produces the content of `pred_probabilities_with_names`) from the render* function which is the recipe of how to construct the visual. the original observeEvent could be an eventReactive. the output$variableValues should be outside of that, and take the result of the eventReactice as its input; it doesnt need redefining each time the button is pressed, its enough that it is hooked to its reactive input it will update as normal based on that.